# How to access server controls like a textbox from an external .js file using J-query?

Tags: jquery, servercontrols

I need to change the height of a textbox using J-query. I need to write this code in an external .js file. How do I access textbox height in J-query in the external .js file?

Answer (score 1):

You can access it the same way in the inline code:

```
$('#<%=mycontrol.ClientID%>')
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter that your js is in an external file, you'd write it the same way inline or external.

If the textbox has an ID you can use:

$("#Textbox1").height();

http://docs.jquery.com/CSS/height